# Javafx - Bounds are zero until seen

Tags: java, resize, javafx-8

In an attempt to fix a problem with printing within the margins, I'm trying to scale my forms so that they'd shrink to the size of the paper it will be printed to.

### Inside `Printable.java` that extends `VBox`

```
public void scaleToFit(){
    double maxWidth = 497.0;

    this.requestLayout();

    double width = this.getWidth();

    if(width > maxWidth){
        double widthFrac = maxWidth / width;
        this.setScaleX(widthFrac);
    }
    System.out.println(this.getWidth());

    //edited out same process for height
}
```

`Printable` will be kept in a `HashMap data.table`. When my printing window is loaded I run `scaleToFit` for each of them. `main` is a ScrollPane.

### Inside `ModPrintCycle.java` that extends VBox

```
//inside constructor

main.sceneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Scene>(){
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Scene> observable, Scene oldValue, Scene newValue) {
        System.out.println("new Scene");
        newValue.windowProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Window>(){
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Window> arg0, Window arg1, Window arg2) {
                System.out.println("new Window");
                arg2.setOnShown(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>(){
                    @Override
                    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                System.out.println(event.toString());
                                lookingAt = data.tables.size();
                                while(lookingAt-1 >= 0 ){
                                    showNext(-1);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });     
    }
});
```

Just for this example, I also added `scaleToFit()` in the button that changes between these `Printable`s. [EDIT: Added the scripts that explicitly show the use of scaleToFit()] Note that `data.tables` is a HashMap containing the Printables.

### Inside `ModPrintCycle.java` continuation

```
private void showNext(int move){
    boolean k = false;

    if(move > 0 && lookingAt+move < data.tables.size()){
        k = true;
    }
    else if(move < 0 && lookingAt+move >=0){
        k = true;
    }

    if(k){
        lookingAt+= move;   
    }       

    show();
}

private void show(){
    if(data.tables.size() > 0){
        if(lookingAt >= 0 && lookingAt < data.tables.size()){
            //tableOrder is an ArrayList<String> for the arrangement of data.tables
            if(tableOrder.size() > 0){
                Printable pt = data.tables.get(tableOrder.get(lookingAt));
                main.setContent(pt);
                pt.scaleToFit();
            }
        }
        else{
            if(lookingAt < 0){
                lookingAt = 0;
                show();
            }
            else if(lookingAt >= data.tables.size()){
                lookingAt = data.tables.size()-1;
                show();
            }
        }

        txtStatus.setText((lookingAt+1) + " / " + data.tables.size());  
    }else{
        main.setContent(null);
        txtStatus.setText("Empty");
    }
}

public void printAll(ArrayList<String> pageList){
    //PrinterJob pj is global
    //conditions and try declarations
        pj = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(curP);
        PageLayout pp = curP.createPageLayout(Paper.LEGAL, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, MarginType.DEFAULT);
        PageLayout pl = curP.createPageLayout(Paper.LEGAL, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, MarginType.DEFAULT);

        for(String p : pageList){
            Printable pt = data.tables.get(p);
            pt.scaleToFit();
            if(pt.isLandscape()){
                pj.printPage(pl,pt);    
            }
            else{
                pj.printPage(pp,pt);
            }   
        }
        pj.endJob();
    // catch statements
}
```

However, whenever `scaleToFit()` is called for the first time (when `ModPrintCycle` is loaded), it tells me that the widths are 0, thus will not scale yet. The second time it is called (when I change between them for the first time), it's still 0. When it finally runs a 3rd time (when I look back at the `Printable`), it finally works and changes the widths as needed.

Since these `Printable`s need to be printed, I cannot ensure that the forms are scaled until someone looks through all of them twice.

How do I force the forms to take their bounds before having to load them?

Comment: Can you show the usage of scaleToFit()? What is showNext(-1);? If it is unrelated to question you would delete it.

Comment: Sorry. I assumed it would have been implied that it shows the `Printable`. I've added the scripts. Hopefully that's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code you posted is not fully executable (i.e. not MCVE or SSCCE), the problem cannot be reproduced. It is also difficult to guess the cause. But I see your purpose, so I suggest instead of scaling it manually, let the printable scale itself automatically through listener:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane( new Printable( new Label( "looong loooong loooooong looooong loooong text" ) ) );
    stage.setScene( new Scene( scrollPane ) );
    stage.show();
}


class Printable extends VBox
{
    public Printable( Node... children )
    {
        super( children );

        Printable me = this;
        this.widthProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Number>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue )
            {
                double maxWidth = 100.0;
                double width = newValue.doubleValue();
                if ( width > maxWidth )
                {
                    double widthFrac = maxWidth / width;
                    me.setScaleX( widthFrac );
                }
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great. I noticed the height appears after the width, so I just repeated it for the heightProperty. Many Thanks